# how to make gitignore to ignore some of the folders inside your repo

Tags: git, gitignore

There are many similar topics on SO and I've read quite a few of them but the problem remained.

I want to be able to put a folder or file name in gitignore so that it doesn't appear in the repo online but remains locally.

What I did:

1. there is a folder with files locally. I created a new repo using this folder using VSC. I can add and remove files locally, commit, and it will work fine - update the files and file structure.
2. then I added gitignore hoping to stop tracking some misc folders inside the working dir but after adding said folders it didn't ignore them.
   There was a suggestion to try `git rm -r --catch .`, then `git add .` files back, commit and it would work. It did not.
3. I tried to `git rm -r --catch` individually. Strangely it only works on some folders. Not to mention I have to do it for many folders.
4. finally, as an ultimate solution (for me, I got mad), I just deleted everything locally from that repo leaving only readme and gitignore. SO suggested that one can't simply ignore/stop tracking files that are already in the repo and you have to do some reindexing and what's not but the point is, if the file was added after gitignore, you can ignore it without extensive bash use.
   Here I just added all the needed files back to that repo locally where only readme and gitignore were. Then I started adding files to gitignore only to find out it wouldn't work. Or should I say some folders would be ignored and some of them wouldn't (top lvl folders inside work dir where gitignore is located). Folders with files, there are no more gitignores inside them or anything like that.

I tried: `folder_name`, `/folder_name`, `folder_name/`, `folder_name/**`. From 3 folders only 1 would be inored.

If I try creating a new folder with a random name and adding it to ignore the file, it would be ignored.

Before any copy/pasting files back to the local repo folder I deleted the hidden git folder inside it.

This is the picture of my structure [ibb.co/F4WrX81](http://ibb.co/F4WrX81)
I just wanted to point out that I've used git casually before, more so to get used to it really, and it was all good. Here is an example [ibb.co/S5y7LBM](http://ibb.co/S5y7LBM) I would just create a project, work on it some time, then add gitignore, and everything would go smoothly

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. I can either redo the whole thing or do some bashing. Don't really care at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sure it was `git rm -r --catch` and not `git rm -r --cached`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a directory structure and a `.gitignore` that doesn't work and in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: caramba - it was a typo on my part, it was --cached indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a filter into `.gitignore` will not delete matching files/directories.
It will make git ignore it on any none specific command. `rm` command included.

So do it in multiple steps:

- Delete (keep a copy if needed) all folders that you want to ignore.
- Commit the changes in a "Delete the useless folders" commit.
- Edit `.gitignore` to add filters for folders to ignore.
- Commit the changes in a "Update .gitignore file"
- Restore ignored folders (if any)

Comment: After using your solution it did ignore that folder I wanted to get rid of, thanks. But I was looking for a more permanent solution. What caused the problem? I wouldn't want to do this every time I need to hide a folder. I used to ignore files and folders left and right when I just started using it and it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

It is suboptimal but here and now it worked:

- remove the repository from git
- create a new folder
- create a repo with this folder
- create gitignore inside the this folder, commit
- put the old files back to the new folder making sure no old hidden git files sneak through
- gitignore works as intended